# How To Turnon Speaker On a Phone Call In Android 13

Tags: android, kotlin, android-phone-call

this piece of code not work on android 13 maybe someone know how to make it work on android 13?

```
      TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK -> {
                // Call answered (in progress) Handle call answered state here
                Timber.d("onPhoneState: CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK")
                val mainActivity = getMainActivity()
                val audioManager = mainActivity.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE) as AudioManager?
                audioManager?.mode = AudioManager.MODE_IN_CALL
                audioManager?.isSpeakerphoneOn = true
            }
```

To turnon speaker when phonecall is in progress via kotlin

Answer (score 0):

In Android 10 and above: Direct control over the speakerphone during calls is restricted for security reasons. Consider these approaches:

1. Default speakerphone: Set the speakerphone to be on by default when initiating calls.
2. Accessibility service: Use an accessibility service to toggle the speakerphone, but this requires user consent and activation.